# Routing Error Undefined method for Controller:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to use a `rescue_from` in my controller that is supposed to be abstract. I need to catch certain custom errors there, so I am trying to eval a string with a call to a method in `rescue_from`.
Here is the code:

```
class Restream::MultipleDestinationsServicesController < Restream::BaseController
  rescue_from "Exceptions::#{self.class_name}Error",
    with: :show_error
  def self.class_name; controller_name.classify.constantize; end
end
```

That way I am getting

````
Routing Error
undefined method `class_name' for Restream::MultipleDestinationsServicesController:Class Did you mean? class_eval```
````

I do not clearly understand what is going wrong here, and so that can not understand what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby what you write inside a class are instructions which are run one by one. `"Exceptions::#{self.class_name}Error"` is executed immediately, but `self.class_name` is not defined yet. So change the order:

```
def self.class_name
  controller_name.classify.constantize
end

rescue_from "Exceptions::#{self.class_name}Error", with: :show_error
```

Comment: I will try it in the morning, +3GMT ;) And before that: would you ever do that or suggest some other way of doing the same thing?

Comment: I am just constructing an abstract controller, since I have several if tgen that have to behave totally similar